# how to get cascading drop down values from two child columns

Tags: multiple-values, cascading-dropdown

I have a cascading drop down where if I select a value from the parent column, I want the child column to be populated with values from two potential matching columns in the relationship list (i.e two relation ship list child columns)

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "AGSL HCP DB", 
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Doctor_x003a__speciality",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Clinic_x0020_1_x003A_Town" "Clinic_x0020_2_x003A_Town",   **<<<<---- these are the two columns I want to check results from when speciality is selected**
        parentColumn: "Specialties",  
        childColumn: "ClinicLocality",  
        debug: true  
    });
```

is there a way to achieve this maybe with CAML Query?

Basically I want Clinic Locality to have the result of these following two, without duplicate values:

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "AGSL HCP DB",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Doctor_x003a__speciality",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Clinic_2_Town",   
        parentColumn: "Specialties",  
        childColumn: "ClinicLocality",  
        debug: true  
    }); 


$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "AGSL HCP DB",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Doctor_x003a__speciality",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Clinic_1_Town",   
        parentColumn: "Specialties", 
        childColumn: "ClinicLocality",  
        debug: true  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it. I basically created a workflow on the relationshiplist to copy all the data i need into seperate records in a new list, and read from that list.